# Subfigure labelling for a single figure

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a single figure containing two plots. The two plots are already labelled within the figure using (a), (b).

[image: My single figure]

So far I have been referencing the figures using the `cleveref` package as

```
\cref{fig:img1}(a)
```

However the `(a)` is not part of the reference link.

My attempt at a work around is to use the `subfigure` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{jheppub}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth} % contains the two plots in a single figure
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./img.pdf}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:imga}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0\textwidth} % the hidden unwanted image
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./img.pdf}
         \caption{}
         \label{fig:imgb}   
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption here}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So now when I reference `\cref{fig:imga}` it returns figure 1a etc. The only problem other than the spacing between the figure and the caption is that I have the figure label `(a)` under the first figure and a floating `(b)` under the second unwanted image.

Using `\caption*{}` results in the labels not being counted, so the references just return the section number.

Ideally I would like to hide these labels, but not disable them as I want to use them in the references.

EDIT.

Using `\phantomcaption` in place of the two subfigure `\caption{}`'s has worked perfectly.

Comment: Instead use `\phantomcaption` command for the empty caption.

Comment: Wow such an easy work around, yet this is the first time I have heard of the `\phantomcaption` command. I have used it for both as neither label was wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion: Could you break up the graphics file that currently contains the two subfigures into two separate graphics files? (While you're at it, you could get rid of the minuscule `(a)` and `(b)` labels in the plots, which are very easy to overlook. Assign "real" captions to each subfigure instead.) hat way, you'll gain a lot of flexibility, and assigning labels to the entire figure as well as to each subfigure (and creating cross-references to each entity) becomes almost trivially simple.

Comment: I gave that a try, but I found it hard to get two images to sit perfectly inline with each other, even after I cropped the original into two separate images.

Comment: @NickRhodes Editing your answer into your question is not a good idea as this leaves this post unsolved. Can you write a self-answer separate from your question? This is perfectly fine here and you can also accept it two days afterwards.

Comment: @percusse: Could you write up an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

subcaption package offers a convenient `\phantomcaption` command to suppress the label generation on the subfloats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.47\textwidth} % contains the two plots in a single figure
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \phantomcaption
        \label{fig:imga}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0\textwidth} % the hidden unwanted image
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
         \phantomcaption
         \label{fig:imgb}   
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption here}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

We can use \Cref{fig:imga} but we won't use \Cref{fig:imgb}

\end{document}
```

Then the result is as desired.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this workaround, see 
[Is there a way to divide ONE figure to reference the subparts of the figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255785/is-there-a-way-to-divide-one-figure-to-reference-the-subparts-of-the-figure)! It is also using `\phantomsubcaption`, but without adding the image twice!!!

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. The key point is to change the format of \cref on the fly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Main caption here}
    \label{fig:main}
\end{figure}

The default format of \texttt{cref} looks like this \cref{fig:main}.
The format of the figure reference is now changed on the fly to be 
\crefformat{figure}{fig.~#2#1{(a)}#3} % change the format to include (a)
\cref{fig:main} or
\crefformat{figure}{fig.~#2#1{(b)}#3} % change the format to include (b)
\cref{fig:main}
\crefformat{figure}{fig.~#2#1#3} % restore the default format
instead of \cref{fig:main}.

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: x]

As you can see (a) and (b) are included in the hyper links. 
To fix the spacing right before the 'fig.' string simply remove the breaks and comments, e.g.:

```
\crefformat{figure}{fig.~#2#1{(a)}#3}\cref{fig:main}\crefformat{figure}{fig.~#2#1#3}
```

The drawback of this solution is that the format is defined by hand. If decide to use

```
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
```

you will end up with a wrong format, e.g. 'fig.' instead of 'Fig.'. I have no idea how to solve this problem.