# Cleveref reference name depending on label instead of counter?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref

Let's say I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\label{a:sec1}
\cref{a:sec1}

\section{Section Two}
\label{b:sec2}
\cref{b:sec2}
\end{document}
```

Cleveref will now reference "Section 1" and "Section 2" because the label comes after a section. But what I need is that it references the label depending on `a:` and `b:`, where I define the displayed name. For example: All labels having an `a:` should be referenced as "Car X" and all labels having a `b:` should be referenced as "Truck X" even though they are both a section.

Note: I do *not* want to change the counter, only the word that is displayed when referencing depending on the label's "namespace"!

Is `cleveref` able to do this alone or do I have to build some custom solution (probably with `prettyref`)?

Comment: well, you should define a `\carsection` and `\trucksection` instead. That's of course solvable as well, and I would consider it more standard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than give special meaning to items based on the labels' "prefixes" (`a:`, `b:`, ...), I'd use a feature that's already provided by the `cleveref` package: *use the optional argument* of the `\label` command to override an item's default cross-referencing name.

In the following example, I first inform `cleveref` about the singular and plural forms of items called "car" and "truck", and then use the optional arguments of the `\label` commands to inform `cleveref` that the corresponding sections' "names" are "car" and "truck" rather than "section". (The `hyperref` package is loaded and the option `nameinlink` is specified merely to make the output of `cleveref` immediately visible.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}    
% provide singular and plural names of the categories "car" and "truck"
\crefname{truck}{truck}{trucks}
\crefname{car}{car}{cars}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}\label[car]{sec:1}
\section{Section Two}\label[truck]{sec:2}
\section{Section Three}
Cross-references to \cref{sec:1,sec:2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my answer at [new command for including a custom string into \cref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125007/new-command-for-including-a-custom-string-into-cref/125075#125075), one can change the labels of `cleveref` (and also work with `hyperref`).  In this answer, I extend that to look at the first character of the label to help decide what the reference should look like.  Here, I create a new macro, `\crefX` to do the job, but it could be made to replace the default `\cref`, if one really wanted it so (I don't recommend that, however):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefX}[1]{\crefformat{section}{%
  \crefXhelper#1\relax~##2##1##3}%
  \cref{#1}\crefformat{section}{section~##2##1##3}}

\def\crefXhelper#1#2\relax{\if#1aCar\else\if#1bTruck\else Section\fi\fi}

\begin{document}


\section{Section One (a label)}
\label{a:sec1}
This section \crefX{a:sec1}

\section{Section Two (b label)}
\label{b:sec2}
This section \crefX{b:sec2} and prior section, \crefX{a:sec1}.

\section{Section Three (c label)}
\label{c:sec3}
This section \crefX{c:sec3} and prior section, \crefX{b:sec2}
and first section, \crefX{a:sec1}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really wanted it to say "Car X" without the actual number, then

```
\newcommand{\crefX}[1]{\crefformat{section}{%
  \crefXhelper#1\relax~##2X##3}%
  \cref{#1}\crefformat{section}{section~##2##1##3}}
```

could work.