# Enumerate caption on itemize

Tags: itemize

When using a caption with a itemize, how can you get caption saying List 5.1.3 or something instead of Figure 5.1.3? A list isn't a figure, so it should be included in the list of figures either.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{blabla}
\begin{itemize}
\item blabal
\end{itemize}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=List]{mylist}


\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\caption{blabla}
\begin{itemize}
\item blabal
\end{itemize}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great, the only problem I have now is referencing the "my list" using cref

Comment: this thread has the answer:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200982/cleveref-reference-name-depending-on-label-instead-of-counter

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, which violates the use of `listings` package, but it has the advantage of making a `List of Lists` entry and uses `\cref` correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings} % http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{List}% Listing -> List
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of \lstlistingname s}% List of Listings -> List of Lists
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{listing}{list}{lists}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\begin{itemize}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Three blablas},label=list1]\end{lstlisting}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\item blabla 1
\item blabla 2
\item blabla 3
\end{itemize}

In \cref{list1}, we describe ...\par
\Cref{list1} describes ...

\end{document}
```

[image]