# FloatingEnviroment over two pages

Tags: lists, enumerate

In my Latex project I have defined a new enviroment to be able to reference enumerates.

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Liste]{mylist}
```

The only problem, is when putting the enumerate inside this new environment, it won't split over two pages as it used to? Now it has to skip to the next page to show the whole list on one page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Liste]{mylist}


\begin{document}
poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion

\begin{mylist}
\begin{enumerate}
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list\item many items in my list\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list

\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\end{enumerate}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure you want a default placement option that includes `!` or does not include `p`  ??? (floats are a box and never break, but list items may be referenced anyway why do you need this?)

Comment: I need this cause I'm not able to reference a normal enumerate, how could I?

Comment: any item may be referenced with \label and \ref in the usual way, how do you want to reference the list as a whole? it normally has no caption or number that you can reference.

Comment: Thats why I use the floating enviroment, because then it can have a caption.  See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239112/enumerate-caption-on-itemize

Comment: You can use a caption anyway, eg capt-of package, you don't need to make it a _float_ which implies that latex can move the list to a different page if necessary.

Comment: Your example would be more useful if it was an example of your real problem (having a referenceable caption to a list) rather than an example of a proposed non working solution (putting the list in a float)

Comment: could you provide a minimal example showing this? It would be great not to use float, and be able to reference it. By the way, placing it in a figure also isn't good, because then the list will be called a "figure".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23103/discussion-between-minihessel-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make something a float to make it referencable.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{mylist}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mylist}{\def\@captype{mylist}}{}
\def\ext@mylist{myl}
\def\fnum@mylist{List\nobreakspace\themylist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion

See list \ref{zzz}:


\begin{mylist}
\caption{This is a list}\label{zzz}
\begin{enumerate}
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list\item many items in my list\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list

\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\end{enumerate}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I get this error: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this(caption) particular \caption could that be related to any of my other packages?

Comment: also, when clicking on the reference it makes the caption appear on top of the screen. If you have the caption placed underneath the enumerate, you won't see the enumerate when clicking the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) package. This allows you to use the floating environment or non-floating way (shown here) on a case-by-case basis, but retain the same captioning capability in either case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht},name=Liste]{mylist}


\begin{document}
poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion poqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ionpoqkweokqw pqok qpok opqkopkop qk opqk opqk poqk opqk opqk qpok qopk qopk qopk qkemwme kwem kkm kwmekmwkemqkmelq mql lqm lqm klqmeklwmqkle mqkl mq qmqm mq mqm qmrkrk kq pqjpij iqjiepjqoiwej iojm kqokqo kqk koqk oqko kqoekqeij imqk mqklenqoineoqn ion

\captionof{mylist}{The caption.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list\item many items in my list\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list


\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list

\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\item many items in my list
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```