# Is there a way to divide ONE figure to reference the subparts of the figure?

Tags: floats, cleveref

I have a figure that basically consists of smaller figures. I don't want to split the big image apart to put it together with latex for convenience. Instead, I want to reference each subpart of the large image with cleverref. I am going to put a node in each picture with tikz naming each subimage (a),(b), ... 
How can I reference this subimage using cleverref so that the reference looks like this: 
Figure 1.1a
The whole reference should be hyperlinked to the image.

[image: Image with four subimages in a 2x2 array]

I am already using the following important packages:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
```

and my cleverref options are:

```
%reference packages
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3}
%options for equations
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{equation}{#2Eq.~#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{#2Eqs.~#1#3}%
{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
%options for enumerations
\creflabelformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
\crefformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
%options for figures
\creflabelformat{figure}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}
\Crefformat{figure}{#2Figure~#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{#2Fiqs.~#1#3}%
{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
```

Comment: Not much of an answer, so I'll add it as comment: You could add `\phantomsubcaption`s and appropriate `\label`s you can refer to later anywhere inside the figure's code.

Comment: This does not seem to work. If I add `\phantomsubcaption`s the figure number also goes up, leading to wrong figure numbers in the following figures. Also, only adding additional `\label{fig: 1_a}`s does not work, as a reference to them via `\cref{fig: 1_a}` reads "section 1.1" and not "fig 1a".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd go with clipping the image and include it four times (this will have no impact on the final PDF size, because the resource will be loaded just once). With `\clipbox*` of the `trimclip` package you don't even need to know the image size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,trimclip,hyperref,cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subcaptionbox{Top left\label{tl}}{%
  \clipbox*{0 {.5\height} {.5\width} {1\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Top right\label{tr}}{%
  \clipbox*{{.5\width} {.5\height} {1\width} {1\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}

\medskip

\subcaptionbox{Bottom left\label{bl}}{%
  \clipbox*{0 0 {.5\width} {.5\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Bottom right\label{br}}{%
  \clipbox*{{.5\width} 0 {1\width} {.5\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}

\caption{A split duck}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A fuller example showing that the references are as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,trimclip}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2#1#3}
%options for equations
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{equation}{#2Eq.~#1#3}
\Crefformat{equation}{#2Equation~#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{#2Eqs.~#1#3}%
{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
%options for enumerations
\creflabelformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
\crefformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
\Crefformat{enumi}{#2(#1)#3}
%options for figures
\creflabelformat{figure}{#2#1#3}
\crefformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}
\Crefformat{figure}{#2Figure~#1#3}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{#2Fiqs.~#1#3}%
{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

A reference to \cref{global}, then to
\cref{tl}, \cref{tr}, \cref{bl} and \cref{br}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\subcaptionbox{\label{tl}}{%
  \clipbox*{0 {.5\height} {.5\width} {1\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{\label{tr}}{%
  \clipbox*{{.5\width} {.5\height} {1\width} {1\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}

\medskip

\subcaptionbox{\label{bl}}{%
  \clipbox*{0 0 {.5\width} {.5\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{\label{br}}{%
  \clipbox*{{.5\width} 0 {1\width} {.5\height}}{%
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%
  }%
}

\caption{A split duck}\label{global}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The following code will create links also without clipping the figure; add

```
\newcommand{\labelphantom}[1]{%
  \parbox{0pt}{\phantomsubcaption\label{#1}}%
}
```

in your preamble and then type

```
A reference to \cref{global2}, then to
\cref{tl2}, \cref{tr2}, \cref{bl2} and \cref{br2}.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\labelphantom{tl2}%
\labelphantom{tr2}%
\labelphantom{bl2}%
\labelphantom{br2}%
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{duck}%

\caption{A split duck}\label{global2}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, this is an option if I explicitly want subcaptions under each image. But I actually don't want it, so it is a bit of an overkill to use trimclip and later on use phantomcaptions to avoid subcaptions. 
Is it possible to use more than one label/phantomcaption for an image?

Comment: If you want to see (a), (b) and so on, where's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the number of figures don't match anymore. When I add some phantomcaptions, the next image has a wrong figure number. LateX skips 4 numbers then.

Comment: @Alex And why should you add `\phantomcaption`?

Comment: I thought that 4 phantomcaptions will give me the result I want. 
`\phantomcaption
  \label{fig: ho_resistivity_a}`
But it doesn't. Do you understand my problem?
If I only add 4 additional labels, the figure numbers are okay, but when referencing it, I get "section 3.3" instead of "Fig 3.3a".

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but I don't understand. I'll change the code to see that the references are correct.

Comment: I need to do that for about 15 images and they are not always so well seperatable into 4 equally sized pieces. So I don't really want to trim each of them. I just want to be able to reference the same image 4 tiimes with different results.
So `\cref{fig: fig_1a}` should give: Fig. 1a and `\cref{fig: fig_1b` should give: Fig. 1b.

Comment: @Alex I added a trick: the important thing is that `\phantomsubcaption` appears inside a box. The `\parbox{0pt}{...}` will not occupy space.

Comment: the `\labelphantom` is acutally doing what I want!!! Thx a lot.
Nice and easy!