# memoir subcaptionphantom without whitespace

Tags: memoir, subfloats, subcaption

`\subcaptionphantom` is nice when the subfigures are marked on a single figure, but the `subcaption` package is not allowed at memoir's house today.

Thus a solution was made:

[memoir label and ref subfigures inside bigger image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412838/memoir-label-and-ref-subfigures-inside-bigger-image)

This however leaves a large amount of whitespace around the figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\newsubfloat{figure}
% =============== defining the \subcaptionphantom ===================================
\makeatletter
% \begin{macro}{\subcaptionphantom}
% \cs{subcaptionphantom}\oarg{list-entry}\marg{caption} is a hidden
% non-printed subcaption. Designed for the case if "(a)", "(b)" are
% already embedded in the figure itself. 
% Roughtly equivalent to \cs{phantomsubcaption} from the \Lpack{subcaption} package.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\subcaptionphantom}{%
  \bgroup    
    \let\label=\memsub@label
    \ifdonemaincaption\else
      \advance\csname c@\@captype\endcsname\@ne
    \fi
    \refstepcounter{sub\@captype}\@contkeep
    \@ifnextchar [%
      {\@memsubcapphantom{sub\@captype}}%
      {\@memsubcapphantom{sub\@captype}[\@empty]}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}

% \begin{macro}{\@memsubcapphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{memsubcap}, adapted
% for use in \cs{subcaptionphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\@memsubcapphantom#1[#2]#3{%
  \@tempdima=\hsize
  \vskip\subfloatcapskip
  \ifx \@empty #2
    \@memsubcaptionphantom{#1}{#3}{#3}%
  \else
    \@memsubcaptionphantom{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \fi
  \vskip\subfloatcapskip
  \egroup}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
%
% \begin{macro}{\@memsubcaptionphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{memsubcaption}, adapted
% for use in \cs{memsubcapphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\@memsubcaptionphantom}[3]{%

  \ifx \relax#2\relax \else
    \bgroup
      \let\label\@gobble
      \let\protect\string
      \def\@memsubcaplabel{\@nameuse{@@the#1}}%
      \xdef\@memsubfigcaptionlist{%
        \@memsubfigcaptionlist,%
  {\protect\numberline{\@memsubcaplabel}\noexpand{\ignorespaces #2}}}%
    \egroup
  \fi
  \@makesubfloatcaptionphantom{\@nameuse{@the#1}}{#3}%
  }

%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}

% \begin{macro}{\@makesubfloatcaptionphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{makesubfloatcaption}, adapted
% for use in \cs{memsubcaptionphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\@makesubfloatcaptionphantom}[2]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \@subcapsize
    {\phantom{\@subcaplabelfont#1}}{\ignorespaces #2}\unskip}%
  \@tempdimb=-\subfloatcapmargin
  \multiply\@tempdimb\tw@
  \advance\@tempdimb\@tempdima
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{%
    \hss
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\@tempdimb
      \phantom{\memsubfig@caption{#1}}{#2}%
    \else
      \if@shortsubcap
        \phantom{\memsubfig@caption{#1}}{#2}%
      \else
        \box\@tempboxa
      \fi
    \fi
    \hss}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{duck}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
%   \vspace{-4cm}
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{a}}~%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{b}}~%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{c}}~%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{d}}~%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{f}}~%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{g}}~%
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some figures.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{a}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{b}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{c}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{d}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{f}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{g}.
    }
    \label{duck}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

So far my solution has been the outcommented `\vspace{-4cm}` but that's imprecise and impractical. Is there a better way of removing the whitespace

Comment: Just wondering why you arentt just using subcaption, memoir should not have any issues with it. Also why those `~` before the `%`'s

Comment: @daleif I did not make the figure, it's from an article I'm referencing. The `\subcaptionphantom` broke when adding `~%` after it.

Comment: @daleif I'm also using memoirs subfloats a lot (for my own figures). I thought those where incompatible with subcaption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

1. in `\@memsubcapphantom` remove the skips and add `\leavevmode`
2. in `\@makesubfloatcaptionphantom` make the box width zero instead of `\@tempdima`

There are probably better ways.

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\newsubfloat{figure}
% =============== defining the \subcaptionphantom ===================================
\makeatletter
% \begin{macro}{\subcaptionphantom}
% \cs{subcaptionphantom}\oarg{list-entry}\marg{caption} is a hidden
% non-printed subcaption. Designed for the case if "(a)", "(b)" are
% already embedded in the figure itself. 
% Roughtly equivalent to \cs{phantomsubcaption} from the \Lpack{subcaption} package.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\subcaptionphantom}{%
  \bgroup%    
    \let\label=\memsub@label%
    \ifdonemaincaption\else%
      \advance\csname c@\@captype\endcsname\@ne%
    \fi%
    \refstepcounter{sub\@captype}\@contkeep%
    \@ifnextchar[%
      {\@memsubcapphantom{sub\@captype}}%
      {\@memsubcapphantom{sub\@captype}[\@empty]}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}

% \begin{macro}{\@memsubcapphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{memsubcap}, adapted
% for use in \cs{subcaptionphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\@memsubcapphantom#1[#2]#3{%
  \@tempdima=\hsize%
%  \vskip\subfloatcapskip % <- removed
  \ifx\@empty#2%
    \leavevmode% <- added
    \@memsubcaptionphantom{#1}{#3}{#3}%
  \else%
    \leavevmode% <- added
    \@memsubcaptionphantom{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \fi%
%  \vskip\subfloatcapskip % <- removed
  \egroup}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
%
% \begin{macro}{\@memsubcaptionphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{memsubcaption}, adapted
% for use in \cs{memsubcapphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\@memsubcaptionphantom}[3]{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else%
    \bgroup%
      \let\label\@gobble%
      \let\protect\string%
      \def\@memsubcaplabel{\@nameuse{@@the#1}}%
      \xdef\@memsubfigcaptionlist{%
        \@memsubfigcaptionlist,%
  {\protect\numberline{\@memsubcaplabel}\noexpand{\ignorespaces #2}}}%
    \egroup%
  \fi%
  \@makesubfloatcaptionphantom{\@nameuse{@the#1}}{#3}%
  }

%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}

% \begin{macro}{\@makesubfloatcaptionphantom}
% Quick-and-dirty analog of \Lpack{memoir} \cs{makesubfloatcaption}, adapted
% for use in \cs{memsubcaptionphantom}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\@makesubfloatcaptionphantom}[2]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \@subcapsize%
    {\vphantom{\@subcaplabelfont#1}}{\ignorespaces #2}\unskip}%
  \@tempdimb=-\subfloatcapmargin%
  \multiply\@tempdimb\tw@%
  \advance\@tempdimb\@tempdima%
  %\hb@xt@\@tempdima{% % <- changed
  \hb@xt@ 0pt{%
    \hss%
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\@tempdimb%
      \vphantom{\memsubfig@caption{#1}}{#2}%
    \else%
      \if@shortsubcap%
        \vphantom{\memsubfig@caption{#1}}{#2}%
      \else%
        \box\@tempboxa%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \hss}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{duck}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    % \vspace{-4cm}
    \def\LABELS{%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{a}}%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{b}}%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{c}}%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{d}}%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{f}}%
    \subcaptionphantom{\label{g}}}%
    \LABELS%
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some figures.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{a}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{b}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{c}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{d}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{f}.
        A figure named \subcaptionref{g}.
    }
    \label{duck}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This still moves the picture slightly down, but it will be the same amount no matter how many phantoms are used (1 `\baselineskip`). thanks.

Comment: The single baselineskip only happens the first time the command is used, that's a bit wierd to me

Comment: I don't see any v movement, only h movement. We should probably use `\vphantom` not `\phantom`. Exactly which LaTeX version are you on? I'm using TL19.

Comment: It was sporadic spaces, plus I changed to `\vphantom` (I don't think that change is necessary)

Comment: the vspace came from me having an empty line after the phantom labels

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\baselineskip` to get the lineheight.

This can be inserted into the `\vspace`. So you can use `\vspace{-n\baselineskip}` where `n` is the number of `\subcaptionphantom{}` commands present.

This solution is still far from perfect, as it is not automatic.