# Referencing sublabels in REVTeX 4.2

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, revtex

I am writing a document using REVTeX 4.2 and I have a single image file already divided in multiple parts (a, b, c, etc..). I want to reference this "subfigures" in the text. Normally I would just create phantomcaptions using the subcaption package, but this latter is not compatible with REVTeX. What should I do?

EDIT: It's important to highlight the fact that I have only a single image divided in multiple parts, but it's a single file. I want to add phantom captions that are mimicking the subfigures labels, but I don't want to use subfigure environments. In practice I have the same problem described in this question: [Subfigure labelling for a single figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100716/subfigure-labelling-for-a-single-figure) but the proposed solution does not work in my case, because I cannot use the subcaption package.

Comment: `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`

Comment: @HenriMenke can you please explain this better? If I add this line of code in the preamble how do I add mutiple sublabels to a single figure?

Comment: Read the manual.  You can find it at https://ctan.org/pkg/subfig

Comment: @HenriMenke at the first page of the manual there is already something that trobles me: "The ‘subfig’package requires the ‘caption’ package by H.A. Sommerfeldt and replaces the older‘subfigure’ package". The caption package is not compatible with REVTeX, so I cannot use also the subfig package.

Comment: Oh Geez! I wonder what the `caption=false` option does...

Comment: @HenriMenke I have the suspect you are not understanding my question. I DON'T have multiple figures. I have a SINGLE image divided in multiple parts, but it's a single file. I want to add phantom captions that are mimicking the subfigures labels, but I don't want to use subfigure environments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89618/discussion-between-alessandro-zunino-and-henri-menke).